# Read Only Dropdown Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to make one of the form into read only based on user's division

here's my form in my view:

```
<select class="form-control" name="division" id="division">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" >-Choose-</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="all">All</option>
<?php
    if($query->num_rows()) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row):
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id_division?>">
        <?php echo $row->name_division;?>
        </option>
<?php
        endforeach;
}
?>
</select>
```

Is there any way to make it read only based on the user's id_division? So once they click submit or something this will also input their own id_division

Comment: You can add 'readonly' => 'readonly' or alternatively what seems like you've tried to do already 
accepted
You can use the read only attribute. You could avoid outputting a dropdown at all if it is not the best element to use in your particular case.

$element->setAttrib('disabled','disabled');

Comment: @Isaac what if it doesn't has to be an option? something like text input? i think it should be like: `<input class="form-control" type="text" name="division" id="division" placeholder="division" readonly="readonly"></input>` isn't it? but i was wondering, how can this form inputting the value of the user's id_division?

Answer (score 0):

I guess from your question that there are more than one `$id_division`, and more than one `<option>` in the select dropdown. In that one $id_division belongs to the current user.

While submitting form, value of this current user's $id_division only need to pass. In other words, by default the dropdown value should be automatically set for the option which belongs to the current user.

For that case you have to check each `&id_division` in the `foreach` loop whether its equal to the `id_division` of current user. And add the `selected` attribute dynamically to the `<option>` if it equals.

for that,

```
<?php
    if($query->num_rows()) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row):
            if($id_division==[id_division of current user]){//You have to replace [id_division of current user] with variable that you keep current user id_division data.

                $selected='selected';
            }else{
                $selected='';   
            }
?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row->id_division?>" <?php echo $selected;?>>
        <?php echo $row->name_division;?>
        </option>
<?php
        endforeach;
     }
```